# Overriding Materialize default input color

Tags: css, materialize

This is kinda dumb but it's really annoying. How can I change the default color of materialize input fields[type=search] ?

By default the color of it is pink and when I do this

```
  .input-field input:focus {
    background: transparent !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .input-field input {
    background: transparent !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
  .input-field {
    background: transparent !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
  }
```

nothing happens I expect that the input field would be transparent but still turns out to be a color pink which is in the way of what I want to do. Am I missing a class here ? 
I can also change its background color and its working great but the problem is I cant get rid of that annoying default color pink.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem either using the code snippet feature here, or an external tool like jsfiddle.net or codepen?

Comment: hi can you provide the html .. that default pink color is nav tag background-color..

Comment: @ChandraShekhar interesting I think that is it :) i'll try it soon

Comment: @ChandraShekhar and it works :) thanks.

Comment: @GilbertMendoza Cool...... :D...

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy and overwrite the rules starting at https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/7fb38e091f9b8add541f1a679b1c08720043645f/sass/components/forms/_input-fields.scss#L35